# getting authentication failure on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-cli

I have suddly started to get the next error when using the jenkins cli:

```
>java -jar <path to jenkins-cli>/jenkins-cli.jar -s <jenkins url> build <job name>
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readBoolean(DataInputStream.java:244)
        at hudson.cli.Connection.readBoolean(Connection.java:95)
        at hudson.cli.CLI.authenticate(CLI.java:634)
        at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:474)
        at hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:384)
```

what am I doing wrong ? using Jenkins ver. 1.567.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like [this issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22346). Parts of that issue have been fixed in Jenkins 1.617, so upgrading might help, but there are still reports that the issue remains "when a key is used but authentication is disabled".

Answer (score 0):

how do you authenticate to the server ?

If you are using a public , private key authentication. Strongly Suggest you to generate a new one using

SSH Key gen for your reference

```bash
bash-4.1$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/users/xxxx/.ssh/id_rsa):
JenkinsCLI
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):(leave blank)
Enter same passphrase again:(leave blank)
Your identification has been saved in JenkinsCLI.
Your public key has been saved in JenkinsCLI.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
f6:4c:be:fc:cb:cd:d3:ee:8c:80:26:a2:57:df:67:14 xxxxx@xxxxxx
The key's randomart image is:
```